# Unable to connect ganache with Hardhat

Tags: javascript, hardhat, ganache

I am not being able to connect hardhat to the local ganache network. I have already connected the ganache to the metamask.

Here is my hardhat.config.js code:

```
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",

  networks: {
    localganache: {
      url: process.env.PROVIDER_URL || "http://127.0.0.1:7545",
      accounts: [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`] || "0xe5bd56d0495f627245970002400325172c3fd589233c2c16c94d23efa33f7495", // Fixing the syntax error here
    },
  },
};
```

Error I'm getting is

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localganache
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid account: #0 for network: localganache - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the private key provided in the accounts section of your Hardhat configuration is too short. A valid Ethereum private key should be 32 bytes (64 characters when represented as a hexadecimal string).

Thus, remove the "0x" in your code should solve the problem since it adds two characters (66 characters) to the private key. Something like this will work

```
accounts: [`${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`] || "e5bd56d0495f627245970002400325172c3fd589233c2c16c94d23efa33f7495",
```

Comment: Thank you it worked!